# End of a predictable story: "flat" or "plain"?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I am looking for an adjective which could work with the "**end of the story**", meaning predictability, shallowness. Now I am deciding between "*flat*" (in [Freedictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/flat) 5th,6th, and 12th explanations work well) and "[*plain*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/plain)" (because it helps to transfer the obviousness, simplicity). Unfortunately, I can't really see the difference between the two synonymes. What would you advise to focus on?

Comment: *falls flat* works (it means *fails to make the impression that might have been hoped for*). Otherwise I think we would describe the ending as *disappointing* or *unimaginative*.

Comment: If the end of the story was as predictable as it's beginning and middle then wouldn't it be "a foreseeable ending", "a formulaic ending", "an inevitable ending"?

Answer (score 1):

Of the two words you are considering, I would choose **flat**.

As in:  [Writers Relief](http://writersrelief.com/2016/02/18/write-happy-ending-doesnt-fall-flat-checklist/)

> How To Write A Happy Ending That Doesn’t **Fall Flat**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the word "[banal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/banal)" which means:

> lacking originality, freshness, or novelty.

Examples include:

> Drake hit us with a 25-song-long album last night, and while
>   discussing the length of albums is as banal as talking about the
>   weather: Ye’s was so short!

— Allison P. Davis, The Cut, "What Songs Should You Listen To on Scorpion?," 29 June 2018

And

> The more banal, the more commonplace, the more predictable, the
>   triter, the staler, the dumber, the better.

— Don DeLillo, Mao II, 1991

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/banal

You might also consider the adjective "[pedestrian](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedestrian)," which means:

> "commonplace, unimaginative."